# Is GeneXpert RT PCR test valid when travelling to Dubai?

Tags: covid-19, dubai

Travelling to Dubai in the next few days, and we need a valid PCR test to enter. We had two options to book at the test lab:

- RT PCR
- GeneXpert RT PCR

The second one gives results within a few hours, while the first one might take up to 24 hours.
We chose the second one, but are now wondering if it's a valid test, as on this official website (linked below) it mentions refusing "rapid PCR tests" (quoting below) and I'm not sure if the genexpert one counts as a "rapid PCR test" since it produces results faster than the other option.

**"Other test certificates including antibody tests, NHS COVID Test certificates, Rapid PCR tests and home testing kits are not accepted in Dubai."**

https://www.emirates.com/mu/english/help/covid-19/dubai-travel-requirements/tourists/

Comment: Where are you travelling from? Did you book your test with one of the laboratories on the list approved by the Ministry of Health https://c.ekstatic.net/ecl/documents/health-screening-documents/approved-laboratories.pdf?

Comment: op has not returned to clarify. voting to close.